# xbuild could not import "$(VSToolsPath)\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" using Travis CI

Tags: c#, mono, travis-ci, .net-core

I am using travis-ci to test my c# project. I recently switched from targeting dotnet core to targeting dotnet framework 4.6.1 so that I can use an external dll that can't use dotnet core. Because of this I need to change the travis-ci from building using dotnet core to using mono because of their linux machines. I've been getting these errors.

```
/home/travis/build/RaikesSchoolDS/Fiserv/BioID2/src/BioID2/BioID2.xproj: error : /home/travis/build/RaikesSchoolDS/Fiserv/BioID2/src/BioID2/BioID2.xproj: /home/travis/build/RaikesSchoolDS/Fiserv/BioID2/src/BioID2/BioID2.xproj could not import "$(VSToolsPath)\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props"
/home/travis/build/RaikesSchoolDS/Fiserv/BioID2/src/BioIDTest/BioIDTest.xproj: error : /home/travis/build/RaikesSchoolDS/Fiserv/BioID2/src/BioIDTest/BioIDTest.xproj: /home/travis/build/RaikesSchoolDS/Fiserv/BioID2/src/BioIDTest/BioIDTest.xproj could not import "$(VSToolsPath)\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props"
```

I tried deleting the xproj files and having them remade because I thought that switching the targeted framework could be the cause of this, however I had no luck. Here's the relevant part of the xproj file for the main solution:

```
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
```

Any thoughts on how I could fix this? Below is my travis build script. I'm trying to keep it simple for now.

```
language: csharp
solution: BioID2/BioID2.sln
```

Comment: .NET Core on .NET Framework requires Windows which should not work on Mono.

Comment: So I'm SOL basically, no way for me to use travis ci?

Comment: there is AppVeyor